# Automating web application with Jacob api and selenium is produces UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, selenium, jacob

I have used **Jacob** Api for uploading files on automating web application with selenium, but it produces UnsatisfiedLinkError. Am new for Jacob api to file upload so please help and thanks in advance.

Sample Script:-

```
public class FileUpload {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        WebDriver driver;
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ionixx/workspace/IXAutomateNew1/chromedriver/chromedriver_linux");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.navigate().to("http://test/admin/#/login");
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("admin@test.com");
            driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("test");
            driver.findElement(By.className("adm-button-action")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/app-root/div/div[2]/div/app-project/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4/button")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/app-root/div/div[2]/div/app-project/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/div/div[2]/label[1]")).click();
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            final String jacobdllarch = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
                    .contains("32") ? "jacob-1.18-x86.dll" : "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
            String jacobdllpath = workingDir + "/" + jacobdllarch;
            File filejacob = new File(jacobdllpath);
            System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH,
                    filejacob.getAbsolutePath());
            AutoItX uploadWindow = new AutoItX();

            String filepath = workingDir + "/home/ionixx/Downloads/123.pdf";
            driver.get(filepath);
            if (uploadWindow.winWaitActive("File Upload", "", 5)) {
                if (uploadWindow.winExists("File Upload")) {
                    uploadWindow.sleep(100);
                    uploadWindow.send(filepath);
                    uploadWindow.controlClick("File Upload", "", "&Open");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3) on port 6511
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 09, 2017 10:56:14 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Oct 09, 2017 10:56:15 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/ionixx/workspace/Test/jacob-1.18-x64.dll which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ionixx/workspace/Test/jacob-1.18-x64.dll: /home/ionixx/workspace/Test/jacob-1.18-x64.dll: invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:151)
    at com.jacob.com.JacobObject.<clinit>(JacobObject.java:110)
    at autoitx4java.AutoItX.<init>(AutoItX.java:181)
    at FileUpload.main(FileUpload.java:51)
```

Am new for selenium automation so please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very tough time until I figured out this. Good luck!

You need to copy the Jacob dll files into your System32 folder (or SysWOW64 folder - depends on the type of JRE/JDK you are using x86 vs x64).

```
Copy these dll files:
jacob-1.18-x86.dll
jacob-1.18-x64.dll
```

and then,

```
paste them in System32 folder:
    C:\Windows\System32

If it still doesn't work copy the dll files to: 
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

Comment: BTW you'll need admin access to copy files into these windows system folders